# Refresh android ImageButton after rotation

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have an `ImageButton` in my fragment which has its background set to an android drawable icon. In some cases that button needs to be rotated (this works). My problem is that when I come back to the fragment after being in another activity then I want the button to be "reset" to its original position.

Here is how the button is set:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    button = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.doButtonThing);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    if (condition) {
        button.animate().rotation(90f).setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    }
}
```

I have tried using:

```
button.clearAnimation();
button.invalidate();
button.postInvalidate();
```

inside the `onResume()` method but none of them work. How can I reset/reload the original button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code of clearAnimation()

```
/**
 * Cancels any animations for this view.
 */
public void clearAnimation() {
    if (mCurrentAnimation != null) {
        mCurrentAnimation.detach();
    }
    mCurrentAnimation = null;
    invalidateParentIfNeeded();
}
```

which gives me the impression that it clears a currently running animation (Although I'm not sure). Instead of `button.clearAnimation();`, you can use `button.animate().rotation(0.0f);` to reverse-rotate the button.

Also instead of `onResume()`, I suggest you to call the function later on, maybe `onStop()`. In the lifecycle, `onResume()` comes after `onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)`, calling it in `onResume()` would invalidate your animation.

Comment: `button.animate().rotation(0.0f);` did the trick, I somehow thought that would just not rotate the already rotated button, but I guess it remembers the original state and resets it. 

Thanks for your help, I will move it to `onStop()` then.